# Starting new session on every curl request

Tags: php

My question is about SESSIONS in PHP.

I am using the following code to start a new session when user opens my website:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

What I want to know is, suppose a script sends "two" CURL request to my website, then will they get a new session each time?

Or will PHP recognize the "second" CURL request from same server, and open the previous session which PHP allotted to this request maker?

Suppose I want a new session started on every CURL request, then is my current PHP code session_start() okay?

Suppose I want an older session to be resumed, on every CURL request, then how should I do that while starting a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP uses cookies to manage sessions. In order to use cookies with `curl` you need to enable a `cookie jar`

For example:

```
curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt  http://www.example.com
```

Note: `cookies.txt` must be placed somewhere your instance of `curl` can read and write to it.
Using this format on each invocation of `curl` should allow you to use the same PHP session each time.

Without the `cookie-jar` argument, `curl` won't persist cookies between sessions. PHP won't see a cookie it recognises, so it will start a new session each time.

More details on the cURL page: https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but suppose my website is not setting any cookie. Will then also curl script receive a cookie, which it can use later? Thanks

Comment: PHP uses its own cookies to manage sessions, regardless of what your web site is doing. Note that PHP has alternative mechanisms for passing the session ID that might also work for you. See the [PHP Sessions page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) for all the gory details.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I have marked your answer as the accepted answer. Thanks.